# Draw Transparent Vertex Buffer

Tags: c++, direct3d

How can one draw the contents of a vertex/index buffer with transparency without passing color coordinates to the FVF and without using a shader, what is the fixed function solution?

Comment: You could setup a render target to draw the vertex buffer to a texture, and draw the texture with transparency later.

Comment: Hey, thats a great idea, I am not sure about the practicality of me doing that, but I love nifty ideas like that, you're giving me some idea's :)